# how to play the audio using javascript (by input)

Tags: javascript, html

```
function playSound(buffer) {
    aSoundSource = audioContext.createBufferSource(); source.
    aSoundSource.buffer = buffer; 
    aSoundSource.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(analyser); 

    var volX = volControl();
    //gainNode.gain.value = 0.1;
    gainNode.gain.value = volX;
    analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);

    aSoundSource.start(0); 

    document.title = document.getElementById("files").value;

    playing = true;
    requestAnimFrame(drawVisualisation);
}

///////////////////////////////////////

function play(){ 
var audio = new Audio('test.mp3');
audio.play();
}
```

second function is working perfectly its i have called particular audio to play its working for button here i want to input a song and play

Answer (score 0):

Havent tested but this is the rough idea

```js
document.getElementById("inputFile").onchange = loadMusic

function loadMusic(e) {
console.log(e.target.value)
var audio = new Audio(e.target.value)
audio.play();
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inputFile">
```

Comment: its taking a the file but its not playing